# Ubuntu 14.04 installation issue alongside windows 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have 32 bit windows 7 installed on my laptop. I now want to dual boot ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7. My laptop only supports boot from bios and there is MBR partition table.

Totally there is 250GB HDD which is divided in 3 NTFS partitions (C: D: E:), 77.xxGB each.

Now I want to install ubuntu on another partition. I tried creating 30GB unallocated partiton, using disk manager on windows 7. Now when I enter Installation, there are always 3 options - Install ubuntu inside windows7 , erase all data on disk and install, and the last something else. So I selected something else. There after when I reached at partitioning screen, there are only 2 partitions detected, 83GB NTFS which is my C: and another 166GB which is the summation of E: & D:. As you can see I have 77GB C: then also it is showsing 83GB. But thats not the issue, issue is where is that 30GB unallocated partition?

Also there is no option to install ubuntu alongside win7. And I don't know actually that what the option "install ubuntu inside windows 7" will do.

[image]

[This the screen which appears after select "Something else" option.](http://i57.tinypic.com/1213e6s.jpg)

Also I want make one thing clear that my disk is dynamic disk. So how to can I convert dynamic disk to basic disk without losing my any data. And will dynamic disk work with windows 7?

Please help me out to dual boot ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a screenshot of gparted, upload it somewhere and post a link.

Comment: I have edited my description and posted the links on which you will find pics. Thannks

Comment: There is no unallocated space. Only 1 MB.

Comment: You have 4 primary partitions, that is the maximum one can have. You have to delete at least one, to create an extended partition. Inside the extended partition you will be able to create many logical partitions. You may want to ask Microsoft how to convert their dynamic disk into a static disk first, before messing with partitions.

Comment: Your "dynamic disk" (aka logical disk manager, or LDM) setup is a non-starter; Ubuntu cannot be installed to such a disk -- at least not easily. (It might be possible with a lot of hoop-jumping, but I've never heard of a successful procedure, so you're on your own if you want to try.)

Comment: What if I partition 30GB from 155GB using Gparted? Will it loss any of my data? Will I be able to install ubuntu on that partition?